# What does double backslash mean in elixir?

Tags: elixir

I looked upon the internet about what double backslash means in elixir. And I came across a code where it is used. But I am still am unable to understand what double backslash does in elixir. The example code will be below.

```
defmodule Concat do
    def join(a, b, sep \\ " ") do
        a <> sep <> b
    end
end

IO.puts Concat.join("Hello", "world")      #=> Hello world
IO.puts Concat.join("Hello", "world", "_") #=> Hello_world
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the double backslash mean in a function parameter in Elixir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563884/what-does-the-double-backslash-mean-in-a-function-parameter-in-elixir)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#def/2-default-arguments):

> ### Default arguments
>
> `\\` is used to specify a default value for a parameter of a function.
> For example:
>
> ```exlir
> defmodule MyMath do
>   def multiply_by(number, factor \\ 2) do
>     number * factor
>   end
> end
>
> MyMath.multiply_by(4, 3)
> #=> 12
>
> MyMath.multiply_by(4)
> #=> 8
> ```
>
> The compiler translates this into multiple functions with different
> arities, here `MyMath.multiply_by/1` and `MyMath.multiply_by/2`, that
> represent cases when arguments for parameters with default values are
> passed or not passed.
>
> When defining a function with default arguments as well as multiple
> explicitly declared clauses, you must write a function head that
> declares the defaults. For example:
>
> ```exlir
> defmodule MyString do
>   def join(string1, string2 \\ nil, separator \\ " ")
>
>   def join(string1, nil, _separator) do
>     string1
>   end
>
>   def join(string1, string2, separator) do
>     string1 <> separator <> string2
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> Note that `\\` can't be used with anonymous functions because they can
> only have a sole arity.

Answer (score 2):

In short - it means "default value" for an argument. However due to fact how Erlang is implemented, in fact it mean "create new function with this argument omitted that will call this function with given value in place of this argument). So your example will be expanded to:

```
defmodule Concat do
  def join(a, b), do: join(a, b, " ")
  def join(a, b, sep), do: a <> sep <> b
end
```